# Resize large image .tiff format to specific file size using ImageMagick and PHP

Tags: php, imagick

I need resize an uploaded image in TIFF format to specific file size less than 95 kB using imagick and php. Can someone tell me best way to get size below of 95kb?
I am using below code but using this code sometimes i got image size greater than 95kb?

```
$filename = "test.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($filename);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(int(40));
$img =  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename).".tiff";
$image->writeImage($img);
```

Comment: Yes. Run your conversion repeatedly, adjusting the dimensions up or down, until a near enough size match has been obtained. You won't get exactly (95 x 1024) bytes, so you will to decide how close is good enough.

Comment: @user1234 halfer already explained the process you need to go through

Comment: You can also specify a compression method. If you do not, ImageMagick will use -compress none. If you use JPEG compression, you might be able to specify a quality. The other compression methods (LZW and ZIP) do not permit quality values to be set. If that does not get you what you want, then you will need to make the image dimensions smaller.

Comment: To combine the above, use divide and conquer / binary search: using JPEG, if the same size and good quality is too big then pick a minimum acceptable resolution, barely acceptable quality and look at the size.  If the size is much smaller than 95 KB then you can try something in between.

Comment: You could instead try interpolation:  `oversize_amount = size / 95 ;  new_scale_factor = 1.0 / (oversize_amount * 1.x) ;`  repeat while size > 95.  The * 1.x is because if the size is 15% too big you probably want to try lowering the resolution by a larger factor like 20-25%

Answer (score 1):

Imagick has a function for that.

```
$filename = "test.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($filename);
// Setting your default compression
$compression_value = int(40);
// Imagick needs to know how to compress
$image->setImageCompression(COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);
// getImageLength gets the length of the file in bytes.
while ($image->getImageLength() > 95000) {
    $compression_value = $compression_value +1;
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);
}
$img =  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename).".tiff";
$image->writeImage($img);
```

Note: This said, you may want to set a maximum number of cycles, because it can just keep compression going at higher and higher levels, with diminishing returns the higher you go. Usually you don't go above 100, so that'd be my recomendation. If the image *can't* be compressed to 95k, you'll probably want to stop at some point.

Comment: You really want to use a divide and conquer algorithm here rather than '+1'. Divide and conquer will find the optimum value between 40 and 100 in 7 steps guaranteed. Adding 1 could take 60 iterations.

Comment: @Danack Please can you explain with example?

Comment: @Danack Agreed, that's the better solution, but I was going with an easier to understand answer. But definitely thanks for pointing that out. For optimization, we could also start with estimating one byte per pixel since Tiff is a raster type, get the length and width of the image, and calculate the raw bytesize before compression, have a table of typical compression ratios, to give us a start point that's likely really close to the target value and then alter for there. Combining the two, we could probably get down to about 2 or 3 iterations on average.

Comment: @liljoshu i got same size into $image->getImageLength() before while loop and 
inside while loop after $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);

Answer (score 0):

A more effecient answer (yet more complex) based on discussion in my other question between Danack and myself (haven't tested yet, still in progress).

```
$filename = "test.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($filename);
// Setting your default compression
$height = $image->getImageHeight();
$width = $image->getImageWidth();
$raw_size = $height * $width;


// Imagick needs to know how to compress
$image->setImageCompression(COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);
// 80 compression shaves off about 40% of file size. Using that to estimate 
// 1% reduction for every 2 compression. This should be refined
// as more data is gained for your specific scenario.
 $compression_value = int(190/$raw_size);
// getImageLength gets the length of the file in bytes.
loop_refine($compression_value, $image);
while () {

}
// This reduces our size just a little more
$image->stripImage();
$img =  preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename).".tiff";
$image->writeImage($img);

function loop_refine(&$compression_value, &$image){
    if ($image->getImageLength() > 95000 && $compression_value < 101){
        reduce_image_size($compression_value, $image);
    } elseif ($image->getImageLength() > 92000 && $compression_value < 101){
        increase_image_size($compression_value, $image);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function reduce_image_size(&$compression_value, &$image){
    $compression_value = $compression_value + int((101 - $compression_value)/2);
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);
    loop_refine($compression_value, $image);
}
function increase_image_size(&$compression_value, &$image){
    $compression_value = $compression_value - int((101- $compression_value)/4);
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_value);
    loop_refine($compression_value, $image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
// File and new size image

$filename = 'imagename.jpg';
$percent = 0.4;

// Content type

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes image

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load image

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize image

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// result 

imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Comment: Actually i want converted image in tiff format. Using GD how to convert in tiff format?So i am using magick library